# How to attach a USB device to a docker container under Ubuntu

Tags: docker

I am trying to give a container access to a USB device on the host. The device appears to exist but docker seems unable to access it when creating the container.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

The device appears to exist:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jun 21 20:47 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

It's a Sonoff zigbee dongle:

```
$ ls -l /dev/serial/by-id
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun 21 20:47 usb-ITead_Sonoff_Zigbee_3.0_USB_Dongle_Plus_1ec67e3b0b86ec11b4cd631719c2d21c-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
```

But when I try to pass it to a container (simple example here), I get an error:

```
$ docker run --device /dev/ttyUSB0 alpine
docker: Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/ttyUSB0": no such file or directory.
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. Can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have permission to access the device or the device is not properly mounted. There are different methods to make the device available:

1. You could give the Docker container privileged rights by adding `--privileged` as runtime argument. If you then check `/dev` from inside the container, you should see all your devices. If the container user has no root privileges, you need to add your user to the `dialout` group: `sudo usermod -a -G dialout <user>`. Also remember to restart the container so that the group changes are properly applied.
2. If you want to access a specific device, which is already connected to the host, without giving the container privileged rights, you can use the runtime argument `--device=/dev/ttyUSB0` as you did. Also add both the local and the container user to the `dialout` group.
3. You could also use `--device` or `--privileged` and just change file permission of `ttyUSB0` if you don't want to add the user to `dialout` (not recommended, more for debugging): `sudo chmod -R 0666 /dev/ttyUSB0`.

I would try starting the container with `--privileged` in your case to first figure out if you see the device from inside the container. And also check `groups` for your local and container user.